# How to install and launch grub-customizer through the GUI?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, software-installation

I have always been a windows user. Thought I would try kubuntu to see how I liked it. I would like to make windows my default, so I downloaded grub-customizer to reset the boot. I  really do not understand linux language so I have not been able to launch grub-customizer.
is there an easy solution for a linux dummy like me?
In windows all you have to do is click install.

Answer (score 0):

How have you installed the grub-customizer? It sounds like you downloaded it from their webpage ... well, in Ubuntu installing things is actually even simpler. You have to start the Software-Center and look for the application you want to install (see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware) for the full description on installing things on linux) - it basically works like the iOS store for Apple or the Play store for Android ...

Then, after installing the grub-customizer in that way, you can start it in many ways - you can go through the list of installed applications, or just hit the Super-key (probably the windows key) and type the apps name (grub or customizer should give you a match in this case)

Comment: Thanks, I did what you said and it worked, I am learning

Comment: @TomStaley: If this answer solved your problem, please click the little grey **☑** under the number now turning it into beautiful green. This means "[yes, this answer is correct](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)"! **;-)**